# Docker private trusted registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I want to delete images in docker private trusted registry.How we can see the available images and how we can delete the older images ?

I'm using registry:2

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From [issue 1529](https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/1529), you can see your images with:

```
curl -k -u 'docker:sdf' -X GET https://localhost:5000/v2/_catalog
```

For each image, you can list its tags:

```
curl -k -u 'docker:sdf' -X GET https://localhost:5000/v2/bkf/ebbg/tags/list
```

Finally, for a tag, you can query its manifest:

```
curl -k -I -H Accept:\* https://<some_url_or_ip>:5000/v2/<image_name>/manifests/<tag_name>
```

([Steven Iveson](https://github.com/sjiveson))

> Use the value of either of these headers (including the `sha256:` part if present) - they should be the same:

- `Docker-Content-Digest`
- `Etag`

And you [need the manifest to delete an image](https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/master/docs/spec/api.md#deleting-an-image)

```
DELETE /v2/<name>/manifests/<reference>

curl -k -v -u 'docker:sdf' -X DELETE https://localhost:5000/v2/<name>/manifests/<reference>
```

Comment: Up to manifest query part it is working fine. But when i try to delete a image with the following
curl -k -v -u 'username:password' -X DELETE https://testregistry.com:5000/v2/test/apache/manifests/sha256:2d277d91257299237d0e2c56503f6cfc567a78092104be93528ea2247a386079e

I'm getting following error:
< HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Content-Length: 78
<
{"errors":[{"code":"UNSUPPORTED","message":"The operation is unsupported."}]}

Comment: What version of docker distribution (distribution being the name of the docker registry project) are you using?

Comment: I'm using "registry:2" image

Comment: Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0

Comment: How to find that out ? I'm just using image = "registry:2" should be 2.0 ?
This is my part of docker-compose.yml file 
registry:
  restart: always
  image: registry:2
  ports:
    - 5000:5000

Comment: @Nanab4u On the server, `registry --version` (https://github.com/docker/distribution/tree/master/cmd/registry). Or (https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/1771#issuecomment-224332927) `docker run registry:2 registry --version`

Comment: Thanks.. I'm using "registry github.com/docker/distribution v2.4.1"

Comment: @Nanab4u Well... that seems fairly recent then. I don't have more information, except it would be interesting to test if the delete part still fails in 2.5.0-rc1, part of the docker 1.12 release train.

Comment: I'm still getting the same UNSUPPORTED error in 2.5.0-rc1. Except DELETE part everything else is working fine. Is DELETE working for you ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Nanab4u No, it doesn't work either. Looks like a bug.

Comment: Looks like its not a bug. We need to enable delete options it seems.After adding REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED: "true" in the environment, i'm getting a different error 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Date: Thu, 07 Jul 2016 07:28:24 GMT
< Content-Length: 70
<
{"errors":[{"code":"MANIFEST_UNKNOWN","message":"manifest unknown"}]}

Comment: @Nanab4u That seems a progress of sort! Not sure about the manifest part though.